# Missing Paho dependency in IBM iot-java github Maven project

Tags: maven, iot, paho

I've been using release version of this github IoT java client: https://github.com/ibm-messaging/iot-java

I'd like to build the source but when I import it into my Eclipse I get a missing dependency error for:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.eclipse.paho</groupId>
     <artifactId>org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
 </dependency>
```

I have tried the snapshot modification in settings.xml:

```
 <profiles>
   <profile>
      <id>allow-snapshots</id>
         <activation><activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault></activation>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>snapshots-repo</id>
          <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
          <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>
 </profiles>
```

But that won't solve the problem. Also, using this settings using Eclipse Maven settings.xml editor as linked from the dependency error message won't make the dependency be found. (BTW, I can't use Paho 1.0.2)

Also, I have seen that in bottom of pom.xml of the project it references RELEASE, not SNAPSHOT, and tried also changing it.

Answer (score 1):

May this is because you are using

> https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases/

not

> https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-snapshots

so Please use this repository instead of yours

```
<repositories>

    <!-- Dependency of the Paho mqqt snapshot is here -->
    <repository>
        <id>Eclipse Paho Snapshots Repo</id>
        <url>https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-snapshots/</url>
    </repository>

</repositories>
```